# Delphi 7 - Webbrowser + CEF audio

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, audio, youtube

my goal is to make a funny application, that will play audio from chromium embedded component from youtube , while video will be shown from TWebBrowser component of another part of this series of movie (just for a joke)...

The problem is, i am unable to mute TWebBrowser in Delphi, however it worked in real Internet Explorer... Its enough to change the
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Play_Background_Sounds to "no"  and Youtube in IE will not play audio (there is also no volume control icon on YT):

[Youtube in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d95oj.png)

I tried to do this one in Delphi:

```
var rg:TRegistry ;
....
    rg :=TRegistry.Create;
    rg.RootKey :=HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    rg.OpenKey('\software\microsoft\internet explorer\main\',true);
    rg.WriteString('Display Inline Images','no');  // for faster download - btw this one worked in TWebBrowser
    rg.WriteString('Play_Background_Sounds','no');  // Not working in TWebBrowser  , neither in TembeddedWB
```

not worked...

Also tried this one  (flagged navigation):

```
  const
DLCTL_DLIMAGES =              $00000010;
DLCTL_VIDEOS   =              $00000020;
DLCTL_BGSOUNDS =              $00000040;
  DLCTL_NO_SCRIPTS  =           $00000080;
  DLCTL_NO_JAVA  =              $00000100;
  DLCTL_NO_RUNACTIVEXCTLS =     $00000200;
  DLCTL_NO_DLACTIVEXCTLS =      $00000400;
  DLCTL_DOWNLOADONLY  =         $00000800;
  DLCTL_NO_FRAMEDOWNLOAD  =     $00001000;
  DLCTL_RESYNCHRONIZE   =       $00002000;
  DLCTL_PRAGMA_NO_CACHE =       $00004000;
  DLCTL_FORCEOFFLINE   =        $10000000;
  DLCTL_NO_CLIENTPULL  =        $20000000;
  DLCTL_SILENT   =              $40000000;
  DLCTL_OFFLINEIFNOTCONNECTED =  $80000000;
```

and then

```
var 
WebPage: Integer;
flags: OleVariant;

WebPage := 'https://youtube.com/ ...';

Flags :=   DLCTL_BGSOUNDS +
           DLCTL_PRAGMA_NO_CACHE +
          0 ;

iexplorer1.navigate(webpage,flags);
```

no success again...

What am I doing wrong?
Every help will be appreciated..

PS: Sorry for my english

Comment: you are aware that you can control play & sound with the [YouTube player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)?

Comment: yes my temporary solution is to generate iframe.html from delphi, first iframe has the following code on the end:   events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady}
...  
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.mute();      the second iframe is not muted..  but i wanted to call "dont play sounds" directly from browser... but its harder than i imagined...